# session handling in expressjs with router

Tags: node.js, express, url-routing, express-session

I'm using expressJS, and I'm a bit confused about sessions. I have 1 single expressJS server, which is reachable from different URLs. Depending on where the connection is coming frmo (which URL is opened), a different database is used to provide the responses. And I can see that the sessions are conflicting.

My assumption is that I should be setting different cookie names, based on the URL of the request, but it seems I can't specify a function within the session config.

Any ideas?

```
var app = express();
var session = require('express-session');

var router = express.Router();

app.use('/a_route', router);
app.use('/b_route', router);

router.use(session({
    genid: function(req) {
    return require('crypto').randomBytes(48).toString('hex'); // use UUIDs for session IDs
    },
    secret: 'JollynakAjollynakAjollynakApamPam',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    name: **THIS SHOULD BE DYNAMIC BASED ON URL???**
}));
```

EDIT

```
//declare session variable
var sess ="";


router.post('/login', function (req, res, next) {

    sess = req.session;

    var uname = req.body.username;
    var pwd = req.body.password;
    var authResult = null;

    sess.username = uname;
    sess.instance = req.baseUrl.replace('/', '');
})
```

And an example AJAX call

```
router.get('/getSomething', function (req, res) {

    service.getCaps(sess.instance, function (response) {
        res.send(JSON.stringify(response));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cookies aren't necessarily tied to your databases. All of your routes share one cookie store. "Name" refers to the name of your session cookie and this applies to all of your routes (that's why express-session is middleware called in `app.use`). In general you will only have one session per express app. If you really want to distinguish these with multiple session stores, you'll want to create multiple express apps to handle your routes.

In your situation, it looks like you should really be using two entirely different routers with two entirely separate sets of URLS. You'll have some duplicate code, but since you're dealing with two separate databases, two different "sessions", and two different URLs it makes sense to separate them. Then you can have unique session variables for each route (e.g. `req.session.aLogin` and `req.session.bLogin`);

```
var routerA = express.Router();
var routerB = express.Router();

app.use('/a_route', routerA);
app.use('/b_route', routerB);
```

Another approach is just to juggle separate session variables within your routes.

```
router.post('/login', function (req, res) {
   req.session[req.baseUrl + 'auth'] = true;
});

router.get('/something', function (req, res) {
   if (req.session[req.baseUrl + 'auth'] { //User is authenticated for this particular database
       //Rest of your code
   }
});
```

Comment: I understand, thanks for this. Do you have a recommendation on how to get a solution where there is one "base" url, e.g.: something:3000, and then something:3000/a_route, something:3000/b_route. The point of which is that I catch the baseUrl, and look it up in the config file, and decide which DB to connect to.

Comment: If they are on the same base URL they should probably share the same cookie store. Is there any reason you can't do that?

Comment: No, you are right the problem probably lies elsewhere. I've posted more of my code. Basically I have a `sess` variable declared outside of everything, and in the login procedure, after lookup in the right DB, I add an 'instance' property. But this results in a behavior that if I log in with ExampleUser1 to something:3000/a_route, then with ExampleUser2 to something:3000/b_route, then the next AJAX call made by ExampleUser1 will be to the b_route

Comment: I've updated my answer. Let me know if it's helpful or not. :)

Comment: it's totally helpful :) many thanks J4G. The thing is... I have currently 5 different DBs, and it'll expand to over 10. So at this point it might be simpler to just start N different webservers on N different ports... I honestly thought that this is a fairly common scenario with less duplication needed.

Comment: It's not unheard of, but does a user really need to authenticate individually for each of them? Could one login give access to all databases?

Comment: The user only authenticates to 1 DB, and the DB will depend on the opened URL. The reason for the many DBs is that I have an app with separate instances for many countries.

Comment: I posted one last change that I think is helpful.

Comment: thank you again! I'll need to think this through from scratch to see what is the most seamless way forward. I appreciate your help a lot! :)

Comment: I don't want to start session for all routes, just after login success from router. how can i do it?